# Projecting the parallel transport of a vector along a curved rectangle onto the osculating plane (page-266 Visual Differential Geometry)

Tags: differential-geometry

> [image]

In the above picture is depicted a projection of an infinitesimal geodesic rectangle with vertices $\hat{h} \hat{g} \hat{e} \hat{f}$ on a general curved surface onto the osculating plane at one of the point of the rectangle. The surface has a metric of form:

$$ ds^2 = A du^2 + B dv^2$$

Hence, the rectangle on the surface is also a rectangle in the map. The vector $w$ is parallel transported along the rectangle.

**Question**: When being parallel transported, the angle between $w$ and the side should be fixed, so the figure is as expected. I am struggling to understanding why the holonomy along $\hat{e} \hat{f}$ is given by $\delta R_1$, it seems so actually no rotation happened.

Comment: I have been stuck on this one page for months now lol

Comment: I find almost every post arising from Needham's book very hard to understand. A geodesic rectangle isn't in general an "actual" rectangle; but I agree that it corresponds to a rectangle in $uv$-space. What osculating plane are you talking about? Curves have osculating planes; surfaces do not.

Comment: Good point, that is what is written in the book tho. I guess what he meant was tangent plane. @TedShifrin

Comment: As you parallel translate along a geodesic, the angle the translated vector makes with the tangent vector to the geodesic does not change. So it's appropriate for $\mathbf w_{\|}$ to look parallel to $\mathbf w$. But, as I said, I have no context for this discussion, as I certainly do not have the book. We can't be assuming that all $u$- and $v$-curves are geodesics, but we can certainly assume all $u$-curves are geodesics. If you're going to continue to post with questions from his book, you'll have to make your questions *far* more complete.

Comment: I mean, they can't be anything else than geodesic, right? because the rectangle is infintesimal in the chart. Therefore, if we have map an infinitesimal segment bcak on the manifold, it should be a geodesic again. @TedShifrin

Comment: This was explained in two pages. I had two options, one was copying whole lot of text and other was trying to take what was critical and post it. I tried to do the second option, I may have made mistake/ missed some information, if that's the case then I am ready to listen and fix it (as I am trying to already)

Comment: If the metric looks like that and both $u$- and $v$-curves are geodesics, then the surface must be flat. This is an easy exercise (e.g., in my own differential geometry text).

Comment: I am not saying whole $u$ and $v$ curve, I am saying short segments along the $u$ and $v$ direction.

Comment: What I'm saying applies in as small an open set as you wish to take. "Short segments" won't do. I suspect you have misunderstood some things in the text ... or the text is just not helpful.

Comment: I'm a bit confused that it is true for any size segments. Maybe I misunderstood ti completely. I'll try this again later unless no one helps